# How can we use google mobile vision facial landmark detection api in ionic framework?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, face-detection, google-vision

I am developing a hybrid app in ionic framework. I want to do facial landmark detection offline. I am not finding any samples available. Please let me know if there is any other plugins available.